# C# ASP.NET WebApi route template not working with uri parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI application with the following controller and route:

WebApiConfig.cs

```
var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("validDate", typeof(DateConstraint));
```

Controller.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:validDate?}/{to:validDate?}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<SimpleClass>), Description = "response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(
    [FromUri]string from = "",
    [FromUri]string to = ""
    )
{

}
```

Constraint

```
public class DateConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        IHttpRoute route, 
        string parameterName, 
        IDictionary<string, object> values,
        HttpRouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        object value;

        if (!values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value))
            return false;

        var attribute = new DateAttribute();

        return attribute.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

The above route is hit even though I pass the following url ie I am not passing from and to parameters but the controller is hit and nothing happen.

```
http://localhost:65190/products/deleted?adfear=2016-07-01 03:30:05&adfaewr=2016-07-01 03:30:05
```

How to make sure the route is hit only when the correct parameters are passed or else throw 404 not found error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel.

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2:Route Constraints](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints)

there already exists a `datetime` constraint.

Also what you can do is just make the last date optional so that if provided a from date, it will filter using the from date to current date.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:datetime}/{to:datetime?}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<SimpleClass>), Description = "response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(DateTime from, DateTime? to = null)
{
    //....
}
```

Based on your comments you can do something like this

```
//GET products/deleted
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get() {
    //...
}

//GET products/deleted/2016-01-01
//GET products/deleted/2016-01-01/2016-03-31
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:datetime}/{to:datetime?}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(DateTime from, DateTime? to = null) {
    //...
}
```

this should now handle the three cases

```
//GET products/deleted
//GET products/deleted/{from}
//GET products/deleted/{from}/{to}
```

**Update**

If both parameters are mode optional

```
//GET products/deleted - including query string will hit this
//GET products/deleted?adfear=2016-07-01 03:30:05&adfaewr=2016-07-01 03:30:05
//GET products/deleted/2016-01-01
//GET products/deleted/2016-01-01/2016-03-31
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:datetime?}/{to:datetime?}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(DateTime? from = null, DateTime? to = null) {
    //...
}
```

**Update2**

based on conversation

you can create a filter model

```
public class DateRangeFilter {
    public DateTime? from { get; set; }
    public DateTime? to { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use that in your action.

```
// GET products/deleted
// GET products/deleted?from=2016-01-01&to=2016-03-31
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]DateRangeFilter filter) {
    //...
}
```

Also remember to do model validation either via filter or within the action.

Comment: My requirement is the fields could be optional

Comment: If they are both optional then calls to the default `/deleted` will conflict with this action. That's because `Get()` and `Get(DateTime? from = null, DateTime? to = null)` are considered the same and the framework will not know which one to use

Comment: How to achieve my requirement if the fields are optional? Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: create another action that will handle the default route for deleted

Comment: Thats brilliant. But again the requirement is only one action needs to be created :(. Is it possible to achieve by using some complex type and use [FromUri]?

Comment: you are trying to force something can cannot be done in one action without encountering the problem you stated in your OP. if you make both parameters optional then the url you showed will map to that action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117713/discussion-between-mukil-deepthi-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make the parameters required(question mark means thery are optional)

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:validDate}/{to:validDate}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<SimpleClass>), Description = "response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(
    [FromUri]string from = "",
    [FromUri]string to = ""
    )
{

}
```

Comment: But my requirement is the fields could be optional

Answer (score 1):

You have to omit the question mark on the constraints and the default values for your parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("deleted/{from:validDate}/{to:validDate}", Name = "GetDeletedData")]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<SimpleClass>), Description = "response")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(
    [FromUri]string from,
    [FromUri]string to
    )
{

}
```